# made simplified Abbyy xml

Tags: xml, xslt, abbyy, mendix

I had made the simplifed abbyy XML after that I need to make the rest API from mendix.Can anyone guide how we import the xml document in Mendix or any document or tutorials from where we clear out the doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mendix you need to use an Import Mapping to convert the XML into Mendix entities before you can use them.

There is a good tutorial on how to import and use XML on the Mendix website: https://docs.mendix.com/howto/integration/importing-xml-documents

There is also a very good user forum on the Mendix site where you can find help from fellow users if you get stuck.